# How to set a bitmap image from local storage to NetworkImageView

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

i want to set a image from storage device to NetworkImageView. Here i am implemented but it is displaying nothing. In picturePath i am getting image path but it is not displaying.
1. I am setting the bitmap image from server to NetworkImageView.
2. Then I am giving edit option there i need to upload local images but it is not going on as per my code

Here my code is...

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE_C && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        NetworkImageView logo = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        logo.setImageBitmap(null);
        logo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
```

Error log...

```
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509): [574] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/tiger.jpg
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509): java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/tiger.jpg
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:127)
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509):     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509): Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/tiger.jpg
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:101)
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
04-10 16:26:12.779: E/Volley(6509):     ... 1 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let Volley's NetworkImageView show local image files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464744/let-volleys-networkimageview-show-local-image-files)

Comment: what's your `picturePath`? print it.

Comment: picturePath is a String it actually holds the path of the Image what i selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Answered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22465264/4670319)

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE_C && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
{
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    NetworkImageView logo = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    //File pictureFile=new File(picturePath);
    logo.setImageUrl(picturePath, new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()), new MyCache()));

}
```

Using custom imageloader cache

```
public class MyCache implements com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache {

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {
    if (path.contains("file://")) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    } else {
        // Here you can add an actual cache
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
public void putBitmap(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    // Here you can add an actual cache
}
}
```

This code isn't tested. use it at your own risk

Comment: I am getting confuse, can u edit my code as per above

Comment: Thanks n i imported those library files, but my error is "The method fromFile(File) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (String)" because picturePath is a String.

Comment: I am struck in above error and any way Thanks a lot :)

Comment: did u check i have updated answer after that? did it work for you?

Comment: The method setImageUrl(String, ImageLoader) in the type NetworkImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String, consumer_edit_profile.MyCache)....If i update like above i am getting this error..

Comment: now check the updated anwser, the error has to go now

Comment: Sorry I am getting errors Please check my error log :(