# Volley library load image from file path

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Until recently I was using `Universal Image Loader` to load images from links. I found out about the volley library and started using that instead. Everything is working fine, but in my app I have a button which selects an image from the gallery and displays is in an ImageView using `Universal Image Loader`. Is there an option in volley which will let me do the same thing(load an image from the gallery) ? And which one should I stick with ? Should I keep using the `Volley` library or change back to `Universal Image Loader` ? Which one is better ?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464744/let-volleys-networkimageview-show-local-image-files) may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparing two libraries :

[Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

Using Volley for local images :

[Let Volley's NetworkImageView show local image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464744/let-volleys-networkimageview-show-local-image-files)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've already changed to fresco. I like it more and I could easily play with cache and everything .