# Android Volley NetworkImageView load image from File

Tags: android

I have volley networkimageview in my project. Earlier i was using picasso for loading image from file. But now i am using volley's NetworkImageView.
I know how to load images in network image view from urls but i have to load image from File. Please suggest.

Comment: You mean from asset folder?

Comment: Try this link it will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464744/let-volleys-networkimageview-show-local-image-files

Comment: No.... from java.io.File object... Piasso has the fuctionality to load images from file or url anything. But i dont know how to use volley at that place.

Comment: I have this earlier  Picasso.with(this).load(mFile).into(mImvDocPhoto1) where mFile is this-:
File mFile
nw i am replacing Picasso with volley...